# String clustering using matlab?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I have a cell array of ~200k entries containing relatively small strings (1-2 words). I'm trying to cluster them based on string similarity. I've tried using levenshtein distances to create a distance matrix (using a loop to compare each string to all other strings) to use hierarchical or kmeans clustering on it but am confused on how to use that once the distance matrix is formed (specifically in matlab). If anyone has any ideas or suggestions they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### k-means cannot operate on distance matrixes

It uses *means*, and squared deviation (=variance) from the *mean* only.

hierarchical clustering works fine on distance matrixes. See the documentation for how to pass a precomputed distance matrix.